# Team Foundation Server and Check-In Project's Databases

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, tfs, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I'm looking for a method to how can I back-up and share project's databases with team...
I'm currently using visualstudio.com (TFS) Tean Foundation Server 2013.
And project's database is SQL Server 2012.

How can I include it to check-in progress to share it with team?

I searched whole Google but results are different from what I'm asked...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL Server Data Tools (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx)

Comment: Could you explain how to use it?

Comment: Now I am not sure I get your question. I thought it was about: how to transform an SQL DB in an easy to manage set of source files.
Maybe you want to automate process in some way to push changes? In which case you may leverage TeamBuild, but developers need to pull changes and sync local DB copies.